# Waiting two minutes to call a method

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a Minecraft Bukkit plugin, I know how to handle events and everything, but I'm not sure how to do this. I haven't actually written the code yet so here's a basic example of what I want to do:

```
public void playerDead() {  
    runCommand(commandHere)  
    //Wait 2 minutes.  
    runCommand(otherCommandHere 
}
```

I just need the part to wait two minutes. Everything else is covered.

EDIT2: Seems I need to reset the delay to the beginning if someone else dies while it's going. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Questions here should __show research effort or attempts__. Please take a __[tour]__.

Comment: What do you mean by "resetting the delay to the beginning if someone else dies"? So if someone dies, the second command is scheduled, but if a second player dies, both commands should be executed after two minutes?

Comment: @Unihedron I'm thinking of like a global countdown clock of sorts so there's only one. Here's a bit more context that could help: When a player dies, I want to run the command "lagg admin stop ClearTask", pausing the scheduled clearing of certain types of entities (includimg items) in the plugin ClearLag. This way when someone dies, they'll have a bit more time to retrieve their items before ClearLag gets them. So there should be just one timer that starts from 2 minutes when one person dies. Then if another person dies while it's still counting down, it would reset so the next had time too.

Comment: ClearLag is open-sourced. (I contribute to the project as well.) Just clone it, add handlers and recompile. Working around it is too much work to bare with. However if you do insist so, [Joiner's answer does the trick](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25420280/3622940).

Comment: Directly altering ClearLag did occur to me but there's a few reasons I didn't. Including: I don't want to end up thoroughly screwing something up, and it'd be easier to update this thing that was all mine instead of having to change ClearLag again every time something else is added like bug fixes.

Comment: Did you consider that, if someone else dies, who died before will get more than 2m to try to regain its items? **Are you looking for a per-player solution?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [BukkitScheduler](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Scheduler_Programming#BukkitScheduler) provided by Bukkit.

You have to save the `BukkitTask` object returned by the `Scheduler.runTaskLater(...)` method to use it later.
Every time `playerDead()` is called, you can reset the delay by cancelling and restarting the task.

```
BukkitTask task;

public void playerDead() {
    // Command here
    if (task != null) {
        task.cancel();
    }
    task = getServer().getScheduler().runTaskLater(Plugin, new Task(), 2400L);
}
```

---

```
public class Task extends BukkitRunnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Other command here
        task = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Joiner, you don't have to construct a static outer class in the package for a new `BukkitRunnable`, an inner static class or an anonymous inner class would do as well.

Comment: @Unihedron I know, but classes exist to improve code review.

Comment: I tried this and it gave me a compilation error in the Task class because the task field didn't exist. So I just went with an anonymous BukkitRunnable where the Task would be and that went fine. It's late so I haven't got time to test it so I'll do that tomorrow and return with results.

Answer (score 2):

Since I see you want to perform your action after the player has died. Then for sure you don't want to halt the main Thread with `Thread.sleep(x);`

What you can do is create a cooldown for the player that passed away.

```
public Map<String, Long> cooldown = new HashMap<String, Long>();

Long time = cooldown.get(player.getName());

if(time - System.currentTimeMillis() > 10*1000)
    cooldown.put(player.getName(), System.currentTimeMillis());

else
    int remains = (int)Math.floor(10 - System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Code reference [here](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/waiting-x-time-before-executing-command.109629/).

---

Or you can create your task to run like this:

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask(plugin, new Runnable() 
{
  public void playerDied() 
  {
    // Your code here.
  }
}, <delay in ticks>);
```

Get a reference to your plugin and pass it as the parameter `plugin`. Or if you are lazy just write it inside the plugin and pass it `this`.

Comment: What is player? You have copied the code from here:- https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/waiting-x-time-before-executing-command.109629/

Comment: I assume he has a reference to the player.

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
    @Override
    public void run() {  
        runCommand(commandHere);
    }
}, 120000);
```